# How to do modulo with bigInt using math/big?

Tags: go

I put 2 things, however it wants 3, i'm not sure what to put for third input and why is it returning 2? z and m? I just need one output.

```
z, m := new(big.Int).DivMod(big.NewInt(100), big.NewInt(1024))
if err != nil {
     glog.Info("%v", err)
                    }
bytePos := (m / big.NewInt(8))
```

Comment: Have you read its documentation? [`Int.DivMod()`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int.DivMod)

Comment: I did not really understand it, can you elaborate it?

Comment: What does this part mean? ```DivMod sets z to the quotient x div y and m to the modulus x mod y```

Comment: @l33t it's clear `z = x div y` and `m = x mod y` in Pascal style or `z = x/y` and `m = x % y` in C style

Comment: Ahh i understand. What is the 3rd input i need to put in, i mean for divmod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doc of [`Int.DivMod()`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int.DivMod):

> ```
> func (z *Int) DivMod(x, y, m *Int) (*Int, *Int)
> ```
>
> DivMod sets z to the quotient x div y and m to the modulus x mod y and returns the pair (z, m) for y != 0.

You have to pass 3 values, `x`, `y`, and `m`. The method calculates `x / y`, and the result is set to the receiver `z`. The remainder of the division is set to the 3rd param: `m`. The function also returns the receiver `z` and `m`.

For example:

```
z, m := new(big.Int).DivMod(big.NewInt(345), big.NewInt(100), new(big.Int))

fmt.Println("z:", z)
fmt.Println("m:", m)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/l29_LrjPoDe)):

```
z: 3
m: 45
```

The result is `z = 3` and `m = 45` because `345 / 100 = 3` and the remainder is `45` (`345 = 3*100 + 45`).

Comment: To add on, as u said u only need 1 output, you can choose to do 
`z, _ := new(big.Int).DivMod(big.NewInt(345), big.NewInt(100), new(big.Int))`
this way u can compile without the need to use the second return